# How to redirect login with Allauth in Python/Django?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

Im working with Python and Django.

I have a manual registration/login, and also I've installed with Allauth a Gmail registration/login.

When the user logins (with the manual login I created), it automatically executes a view which shows the differents things the user can do and information related to the user. The url is: http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/9

[screen capture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHPGr.png)

In relation with Gmail, the user can register and login. But, when it logins, sees the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/?(...), which confirms it is logged in.

[screen capture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnLiE.png)

I understand I should create a view in the social_app app, in order to connect the Gmail user with the information in the database. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to go to your `settings.py` and set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/dashboard/9"`

Check out the docs here, they are pretty complete: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html